# How to convert a mp3wav to uncompressed wav using sox?

Tags: audio, wav, file-conversion

how do you convert a mp3wav (a compressed wav in mp3 form) to uncompressed wav (PCM) using sox?

mp3wav sample files can be downloaded here: http://www.clayloomis.com/simsong.html

Answer (score 1):

I would have thought the following would simply work:

```
sox file.mp3 file.wav
```

It may be your version of sox doesn't handle MP3 files at all.  I think this happened to me with the default RPM for openSUSE recently...

Comment: no. it's not a .mp3 file. it's a compressed .mp3 in a .wav file.
i have the latest version SoX 14.2.0.